# show white spaces only when region is selected

Tags: region, whitespace

**whitespace-mode** will show the whitespace all the time in entire buffer,
Is there the way to show whitespaces only when the region is selected. which is pretty cool to have, does there mode exist for such feat or an configuration.

There is exists the similar functionality in sublime editor, as show in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, in addition to "show whitespace only when the region is selected" did you also mean you *only* want whitespace to show in the selected region?

Comment: yes, within the selected region only, similar to what sublime text does.

Comment: Show a screenshot of "what sublime text does" (few readers will have used it), and point out any particularly aspects which are most important (as I'm doubtful that `whitespace-mode` can be adapted easily, but maybe something else can be done which would suffice).

Comment: This is theoretically possible by recreating the features of whitespace mode using overlays or other tools, but as is, you can't configure whitespace mode to do this, whitespace mode uses display tables. It is not possible to have a display table apply to part of a buffer, it must be applied to the whole thing. Is there a specific feature of whitespace mode that is most important? Such as just displaying space or tab characters as a different character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This maybe what your are looking for:

https://github.com/twlz0ne/whitespace4r.el

[image]

Comment: finally, what I wanted, after so long time.. but buggy but workable.